# Unable to fetch complete file in Unity

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine

I am using the following code to save data to a file:

```
void save()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/MyData.dat",FileMode.Append);
    MyData data = new MyData ();
    data.s = input.text;
    input.text="";
    bf.Serialize (file, data);
    file.Close ();
}
```

And the following code to load data from the saved file:

```
public void load()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath+"/MyData.dat",FileMode.Open);
    MyData data = (MyData)bf.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();
    name = data.s;  //returns only one string
}

[Serializable]
class MyData
{
    public string s;
}
```

I am able to append multiple strings to a file, but when I am accessing them using

```
name = data.s;
```

it only returns a single string. Can anyone help me to sort out how ho print all the strings saved in the file.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in **save()** you appending not a new string but a new MyData object, contained single string. And in **load()** you are loading only first serialized MyData object.

Comment: Now, I am using sqlite instead of seriazable class. It would be great if you could help me with this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944561/copy-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder-to-android-persistentpath-in-unity3d