# copy sqlite database from assets folder to android persistentpath in unity3d

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have a squlite database in assets folder with name MyDatabse.s3db and I want to copy it to android Application.persistentdatapath.
I have used the following code

```
string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/MyDatabase.s3db";
if (!File.Exists (filepath))
{
WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/MyDatabase.s3db");
Debug.Log("yield done");
while(!loadDB.isDone) {}
File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDB.bytes);
Debug.Log("copy done");
}
```

The database is created in the Application.persistentDataPath path but it is empty.

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) be of any use?

Comment: It is for java file used in eclipse android, it can't be used here.